# Keep annotated class in Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, roboguice

I have a bunch of classes that use e.g. an @Singleton annotation like so

```
@Singleton
public class ImageCache
```

that I would like to keep. How can I configure a proguard -keep statement so it applies to all classes that have that annotation.

Btw in terms of context I need this for an app using Roboguice on Android, which is why I added the tags. Might help others.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

ProGuard is based on a java-like configuration with wild-cards. It does require fully qualified class names. This should work:

```
-keep @com.google.inject.Singleton public class *
```

Comment: This one is a piece of gold. It's damn usefull to keep jackson 1, jackson 2 and gson annotated classes. ;) Eric, I believe proguard manual should be more explicit about keeping annotated classes, methods, fields, etc.

Comment: I had to also add keepclassmembers. But you gave a good idea, so +1

Comment: Also if you use custom Annotations make sure the RetentionPolicy is CLASS or RUNTIME, otherwise proguard will not be able to find them.

Answer (score 20):

First define an annotation

```
public @interface DoNotStrip {}
```

Then put this in proguard.cfg:

```
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.something.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.something.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.something.DoNotStrip *;
}
```

Comment: Hi, for those who find this answer applicable to their cases, there is a predefined annotation @androidx.annotation.Keep

Comment: @Inliner The Keep annotation refers to keeping the class from being removed during minify if it's not accessed

Comment: @Didi Thank you, it is indeed true. The same as the proguard rule. The difference is in the number of tweaks available when you are using them. In the following article, there is a description of when to use each of them. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9 Also you can look at predefined proguard rules by Android Studio and see how to create your own annotation.