# How to avoid that proguard obfuscates the classes annotated with @OnStart

Tags: obfuscation, netbeans-7, proguard, netbeans-platform

In applications based on NetBeans Platform 7.2, it is possible to
replace the ModuleInstall classes with this code:

```
import org.openide.modules.OnStart;
import org.openide.modules.OnStop;

@OnStart
public final class Installer implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       System.out.println("enable something...");
   }

   @OnStop
   public static final class Down implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("disable something...");
       }
   }
}
```

My problem is that, after obfuscation, the class loader does not find
the annotated classes.

In the Proguard configuration I added (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622212/keep-annotated-class-in-proguard))

```
-keep @org.openide.modules.OnStart class *
```

But apparently this is not enough or it does not work.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: @jolivier 
   `-keepattributes *Annotation* `
does not help.

Answer (score 1):

From I could figure out, you need to explicitly keep the annotations that you use to keep whatever specifications. So, in your case, adding

```
-keep enum org.openide.modules.OnStart
```

would allow this annotation to be used as a selector.
Proguard really ought to include a warning message if annotation selectors are not actually matching. It also doesn't really make sense to keep the annotation, especially if it's not of runtime retention.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `-keepattributes *Annotation*`? It might do the trick, based on [proguard usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html).