# How to set proguard rule for Room library on Android

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-proguard

In my application i want use `Room` library for use **database**, and for finally for **generate APK** i enable **minify** option (**proguard**) in `Build.Gradle` .

**I use below version of Room library :**

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

**I write below codes in proguard-rules :**

```
-dontwarn class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
-dontwarn interface android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
-dontwarn class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn interface android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
```

**But when generate APK show me below error in `Build` tab :**

```
Unknown option 'android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource' in line 39 of file '/Volumes/M/Test Projects/MyApp/app/proguard-rules.pro'
```

**Show me error for this line :**

```
-dontwarn class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below lines for `keep` section in your proguard file.

```
-dontwarn android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

Comment: thanks this fixed, but again show me this error : `Expecting java type before ';' in line 71 of file '/Volumes/M/Test Projects/MyApp/app/proguard-rules.pro'`
 for this line : `-keepclasseswithmembers class * {native ;}` .  how can i fix it too? please help me

Comment: use `native <methods>;`  you need to add tag `<methods>`

Answer (score 20):

If you use androidx

```
-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
-keep @androidx.room.Entity class *
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**
```

Comment: what about the entities, don't they need any -keep's ?

Comment: Solved entities by adding: `-keep @androidx.room.Entity class *`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622212/keep-annotated-class-in-proguard)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line in the proguard file

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

And your model entity should look like this add SerializedName("key")

```
@Entity
data class ListElement(

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
val id: Int,

@SerializedName("userId")
@Expose
val userId: Int,

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
val title: String,

@SerializedName("completed")
@Expose
val completed: Boolean
```

)