# Does Room android library come with in built pro-guard rules

Tags: android, android-room, proguard, android-r8

I have an android app which is using Room library. I am **not** using @ColumnInfo.
I built the release version of app with R8 **without** any pro guard rules for Room. My app works fine and db operations are working fine in release apk.

my question are:

1. Does the room library comes with in built pro guard rules?
2. I have seen many articles where they say that we have to manually add rules for entity and db classes, do we have to?
3. If library doesn't come with rules then how come my app is not crashing anywhere?
4. Is there any good resource where I can find pro-guard rules for libraries?

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700773/how-to-set-proguard-rule-for-room-library-on-android) and [This](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/767ab25a9670eb0083bafa65f8d786bb).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the second link and answering 4th question. but first link doesn't provide answer to any of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question :

1. Does the room library comes with in built pro guard rules?
   -- **yes it does, you can find them [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/room-runtime/proguard-rules.pro)**
2. I have seen many articles where they say that we have to manually add rules for entity and db classes, do we have to?
   -- **No there is no need to add manually**
3. If library doesn't come with rules then how come my app is not crashing anywhere?
   -- **NA**
4. Is there any good resource where I can find pro-guard rules for libraries?
   -- **So far I also found [this](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/767ab25a9670eb0083bafa65f8d786bb) as given by @ADM above**